# Azure and endpoint - allow only one IP to connect

Tags: azure, endpoint

I am trying to configure my Azure VM to only allow connections on say ftp/sFPT from specific IP-addresses, but I seem to be completely unable to find out if this is at all possible.

I am able to create the endpoint, thus effectively opening the firewall, but I would not allow everyone to connect, just one or two specific IP's

Answer (score 5):

Old question, I know but still in the search results - and things have changed since the only other answer here.

You can edit the Access Control List via the 
Azure Management Dashboard:
Virtual Machines -> select vm -> Endpoints -> select endpoint -> Manage ACL

or the Preview Portal:
Select vm -> All settings -> Endpoints -> select endpoint

Enter the name for the ACL entry, "Permit" for action and then enter the [CIDR notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) for the IP Address sub range you want to allow.  In this case a single IP address of 1.2.3.4 will require an entry of 1.2.3.4/32 and another entry to cover your second (and subsequent IP addresses unless they are contiguous and you can define a range).

Having this permit entry will create an implied Deny to 0.0.0.0/0 (which is deny access for everyone - but only after allowing access for your IP address)

Answer (score 0):

At the time being (**4 SEP 2013**) the only way to set [ACL (Access Control List)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-acl/) on an Endpoint is via Management API (REST) or Azure PowerShell commandlets:

- [This article shows you how to manage ACLS with PowerShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-acl-powershell/)
- [And this one - with Management API (REST)](http://convective.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/setting-an-endpoint-acl-on-a-windows-azure-vm/)

Comment: Although undocumented, it is possible to use the Service Management API to set ACLs. This is, in fact, how the PowerShell cmdlets do it. I described the technique in this post:
http://convective.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/setting-an-endpoint-acl-on-a-windows-azure-vm/

Comment: Hey Neil, my second link is referring your exact post ;)